# Assigning decimal zero to a C pointer

Tags: c, pointers, null-pointer

```
//line 2 causes the program to terminate
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{   
 int *qi = 0;  //1 -- making qi a null pointer
 if(qi==NULL) printf("Null\n");
 else printf("Not Null\n"); 
 *qi =0; // 2  ---  assigning *qi a decimal zero value.
 return 0;
}
```

comment number 2 in the above code terminates the program whereas  adding  one line

```
qi =  &zero;
```

in the above code, before comment number 2 prevents this as shown below

```
// this code works fine
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
 int *qi = 0;  //1
 if(qi==NULL) printf("Null\n");
 else printf("Not Null\n"); 
 int zero =0;
 qi = &zero;
 *qi= zero;  //2
 printf("%d\n",*qi);
 return 0;
}
```

why is this happening? Explain as if you are explaining to a child.

Comment: Without properly allocating a block of `sizeof int` bytes at memory address 0, the statement `*qi = 0` (preceded by `qi = 0`) yields undefined behavior. And with `qi = &zero`, you are setting `qi` to point to a properly allocated block of `sizeof int` bytes, which allows you to safely perform `*qi = 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is simple... an integer pointer points to block of memory allocated by an integer. A null pointer has no memory to point. so by *qi =0; you are de refrencing a null location, which actually does not exist. And in your second case you point your integer pointer to an integer variable zero so that works.

Comment: Types don't allocate anything. And in C it is not the object which defines the type of access, but the type used to access it (using a different type invokes undefined behaviour in many situations).

Answer (score 1):

```
int *qi = 0;
```

`qi` is a null pointer.  You can't do much with a null pointer.  In particular, you mustn't dereference it to read or write:

```
*qi = 0; // WRONG - illegal use of a null pointer.
```

Now, we execute

```
qi = &zero;
```

`qi` is no longer a null pointer, as we stored the address of `zero` in it.  **`qi` *points to* `zero`**.

```
*qi = zero; // RIGHT (but pointless)
```

This copies the value stored in `zero` to the location pointed to by `qi`.  We know that `qi` points to `zero`, so this is now the same as writing

```
zero = zero;
```